# PubNub message text returning nil?

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

When I send a message using iOS to a PubNub channel, I can use the didReceiveMessage function to get that message and put it in my tableView. However, if I send a message via a client in the Dev Dashboard, message.data.message returns nil after I try to cast it as a String. Here's the function in question:

```
func client(client: PubNub, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessageResult) {
        print("Received: %", message.data.message)

        let newMessage:String? = message.data.message as? String
        print(newMessage) // returns nil
        self.messagesArray.append(newMessage!)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.messageTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

I get the following response in console from `print("Received: %", message.data.message)`:

```
Received: % Optional({
    text = test;
})
```

However, `print(newMessage)` is returning nil. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm getting the same thing when I try to get messages from the historyForChannel function.

```
//get history
        pubNub.historyForChannel("channelname" as String, withCompletion: { (result, status) -> Void in
            print(status)
            if status == nil {
                if result!.data.messages.count > 0 {
                    let historyMessages = result!.data.messages.description as? [String]
                    print(result)
                    for item in historyMessages!{
                        self.messagesArray.append(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

historyMessages is nil, even though result prints:

```
Optional({
    Operation = History;
    Request =     {
        Authorization = "not set";
        Method = GET;
        Origin = "pubsub.pubnub.com";
        "POST Body size" = 0;
        Secure = YES;
        URL = "...redacted";
        UUID = "...redacted";
    };
    Response =     {
        "Processed data" =         {
            end = 14609023551682481;
            messages =             (
                "technically ",
                                {
                    text = "Well..ok then";
                },
                hi,
                "really ",
                                {
                    text = "Well..ok then";
                },
```

How do I get the text from these returned messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From behaviour and fact what history fetch printed out *status* object means what you probably configured your client with *cipherKey*. That *status* object which you receive probably has category set to decryption error.
If you want to use encryption - you should use same key for all clients, or they won't be able to decrypt sent messages. If *cipherKey* is set, client automatically try to decrypt data and it will fail if regular text has been received.

Make sure both (console and iOS client) configured with same *cipherKey* or if you don't need it, make sure what it not set on any of clients.

Best regards,
Sergey.